# I can not open any of evolution's windows when I start evolution

Tags: 20.04, email, evolution, dbus

When I start evolution on blank or new window it appears as an icon in the top right. Clicking on it shows windows are there but they will not open. I have used *apt* to remove evolution and reinstall but the problem remains. One message I received in terminal was: "Your app did not unregister from D-Bus before destruction. Try g_application_run()"; but neither I nor terminal could make any sense from that.